# Copy/Paste doesn't work in Xrdp (ubuntu host, windows client)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-desktop, mate

Copy/Paste doesn't work for me on my remote desktop session from windows to ubuntu.
I tried this on Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity (xrdp version 0.5.0), and ubuntu 15.10 with mate (xrdp version 0.6.1), I'm using Windows 7 Professional as the client
(workarounds that are better than just using the file-system are also welcome, or even examples for environments where this actually work well).

Comment: Try this [solution](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9285)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I tested the script step by step in my 12.04 system until the stage where it failed to install mate. When I'll get to 15.10 or higher I'll post about it (script was tested in 16.04 by the developers).